# Can't we link a grails form to a bean

Tags: grails, gsp

As in Struts n JSF, we link a form to a bean(eg. backing bean in JSF). 
But in grails, we are using `params` to set values of the bean. Is there any other way to automatically map a form to the bean?

Answer (score 1):

Grails has the possibility to auto bind values from the params map to a given domain instance / command object. This can be achieved by defining the correct beans as a parameter for your controller methods. Take this example:

Controller:

```
class AuthorController {
  def save(Author author) {
    // matching param values are bound to the author instance
    assert params.name == "myName"
    assert author.name == "myName"
  }
}
```

gsp with form:

```
<g:form controller="author" action="save">
  <g:field name="name" value="myName" />
  <g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" />
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is better to use the Command Objects provided by Grails, the domain class can be wrapped only matching the name of the form fields with the attributes names of the class.
But Command Objects can provide an intermediate layer of validation and abstraction to generate the model bean.

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/single.html#commandObjects